# how to get array index from mongoose Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

```
//index.js
```

```js
let countryName = {
  "name"=["Bangladesh","India","Australia"]
}
```

```js
//Output Section

let getCountryData = awaitDataModel.find({$indexOfArray:{CountryName:"Bangladesh"}})

console.log(getCountryData);
//Expecting Output : 0
```

**I want the index of array from mongoose data set**

Answer (score 0):

`$indexOfArray` is an [aggregate operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/).
Here's a [link](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/mongoose/aggregate) that shows how to do aggregate in mongoose.

```
    if the array is ["Bangladesh", "India", "Australia"]
    I would try something like this

    awaitDataModel.aggregate([
        { $indexOfArray: array, "Bangladesh" }
    ]);
```

The point is it's an aggregate method and you're using `.find`.  The above was just pseudo code

Comment: without aggregate operator how i find the index

Comment: @S.M.Turag. You have to show me what the document looks like in the DB. Also maybe let me know if you know how to find the index in regular js without mongoose. My solution would be to find the document and use something like `findIndex` or `indexOf` on the array in the document once you get the result from the `.find`.